# Matplotlib hexbin memory error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a hexbin plot in python of a rather large data set. The two arrays containing the data are 35 million entries long. However, they only take up 1.5 GB of memory and I have more than 4 GB of memory available. Hexbin fails with a memory error.

```
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "plotmodel.py", line 20, in <module>
plt.hexbin(d,t,m, bins='log', gridsize=20, xscale='log', lw=1, edgecolors='black',    alpha=0.8, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2142, in hexbin
ret = ax.hexbin(x, y, C, gridsize, bins, xscale, yscale, extent, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, reduce_C_function, mincnt, marginals, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 6035, in hexbin
iy2 = np.floor(y).astype(int)
MemoryError
```

Are there any fundamental reasons why hexbin doesn't work on large data sets or is the error due to hardware limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `hexbin` makes several `np.ndarray`s that are the same size as the input data (by rough count I got to *8*!).  There is nothing *fundemental* about this, it is written this way, its done to get the vectorization speed up from `numpy`.

I would suggest pulling the `hexbin` out of mpl, split it into three parts, the first part which sets up details of the hexarray, the second which adds data to an `accum` array (so you can work on you data in chunks), and the third part which takes `accum` and the output of the first part to actually make the plot.